npx shadcnui@latest init button input is not working
When I am typing npx shadcnui@latest init button input in my nexjs app it gives the error:
npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shadcnui - Not found npm ERR! 404 npm ERR! 404  'shadcnui@latest' is not in this registry. npm ERR! 404 npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\R.A\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-09-15T17_18_49_886Z-debug-0.log

I am using vscode and node version 20.17.0 through nvm
Next.js v14.2.11.

Try adding component too

Did my answer or @user27327621's answer help you? If it did please accept one of them so that other users can find the best answer quicker. See What should I do when someone answers my question

In august 2024 Schadcn over hauled the CLI with various new features you can find here. You are using a command that does not exist anymore.
Now to create an app run:
npx shadcn@latest init

Here is the link to the npm package.
If you want to use the old CLI the command for that is:
npx shadcn-ui@latest init

But you shouldn't use that for new projects.
